# How to execute BarCode scanner from ZXing sources on Java, Android?

Tags: java, android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

I have just made application using BarCode scanner (ZXing 1.7). User doesn't use bar code scanner on his phone, therefore I can't add external Bar Code scanner into my application. I have added ZXing sources for into my project, but I don't know how I can execute it without intents. Please, help me.

Update: or how can I make that external bar code scanner will be installed automatically with my application?

Comment: I will improve it asap, but now I'm confused, please give me an idea!

Answer (score 2):

You can't install the external barcode scanner to be installed automatically. What you could do is to check if it is installed, and if not show a dialog asking the user wether they want to install it (this will take the user to the app market link).

If you want to avoid this, you can integrate directly the ZXing library but it requires more work. The barcode scanner app is open source so you can see how to do it from there.

Comment: I have and they provide an integration Intent, use that.  read the documentation in that file and it will tell you how to do exactly what @JJJ just said to do.

Answer (score 1):

If the zxing barcode scanner is installed in the mobile, its very easy:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                                "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");//for Qr code, its "QR_CODE_MODE" instead of "PRODUCT_MODE"
                        intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);//this stops saving ur barcode in barcode scanner app's history
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and in `OnActivityResult`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String contents = 

data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"); //this is the result
    }
else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

         // Handle cancel

}
```

If its not installed: u can put this code in try-catch block and catching the exception, u can do this:

```
Uri marketUri = Uri
                                .parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
                        Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                marketUri);
                        startActivity(marketIntent);
```

So it redirects the app to android market and ur app continues running once if the barcode scanner is installed.

If u dont want to use the other app in ur app, U have to download zxing library and try using the classes from core.jar file(it is created using apache ant). Follow this tutorial to do that: `http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the provided [Intent-based integration code](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent). It's very easy. It will send the user to Market to download the app. This is much better than trying to automatically install it for at least three reasons. First, I do not think users expect apps to install other apps and probably don't like it. Second it will only possibly work if the user has set the device to allow third-party apps from outside Market. Finally, you will be installing a potentially old version.